# Javascript array grouping value

Tags: arrays

I have an array grouping. My array value is

```
var arr = [ 'One', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Two' ];
```

I want the array's value to be

```
arr = [ 'One', 'Two', 'Three' ];
```

How do I group by array value?

Comment: You'll need to loop your array and build a second one with unique values...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution like the one I've built for you in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7MJCK/4/). You could also use the `uniq` function from [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq). However, my advice to you is to:

1. think about the problem
2. get some before and after data
3. try to solve the problem by programming
4. compare the output of your solution applied to your "before" data with the "after" data.

This way you are likely to not only solve the problem, but also to grow as a programmer.

Welcome to StackOverflow!